Pandoc Template to Convert Markdown Blockquotes nested in Lists
I am trying to create a custom .latex template to use when doing pandoc markdown to pdf conversions. The template works great except I cannot get markdown blockquotes (signified by >) to format when nested in lists. Below is the current result I get where the nested blockquotes are not processed properly.

I have been running the command:
pandoc test.txt -o output.pdf --from markdown --template test_template --pdf-engine=xelatex --metadata=title:Title --metadata=date:date

Here is my example markdown:
1. **Test heading**

   - **Person 1**:
>*"A great quote by Person 1"*
     
     The quote above is a great quote.                                                    
2. **Heading 2**

   - **Person 2**:
     > *"A great quote from Person 2"*
     
     Here, you can see the great quote from Person 2.
     
> *"I want block quotes to appear like this (but the ones above should be properly indented)"*

Here is my template:
% Pass options to tcolorbox before loading any package
\PassOptionsToPackage{most}{tcolorbox}
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

% Set page margins
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

% Use Calibri font
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Calibri}

% Single line spacing
\usepackage{setspace}
\singlespacing

% Paragraph formatting
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{4pt} % Reduced spacing between paragraphs

% Unicode support
\usepackage{unicode-math}

% Define \tightlist for Pandoc
\providecommand{\tightlist}{%
  \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}}

% Consistent list spacing and customization
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist{nosep} % Remove extra spacing in all lists

% Load graphicx and adjustbox for scaling and alignment
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

% Define a scaled and vertically adjusted filled-in bullet
\newcommand{\scaledbullet}{\raisebox{-0.1em}{\scalebox{1.2}{\textbullet}}}

% Define a scaled and vertically adjusted hollow circle bullet
\newcommand{\scaledopenbullet}{\raisebox{-0.25em}{\scalebox{1.8}{\textopenbullet}}}

% Assign the scaled bullets to respective list levels
\setlist[itemize,1]{label=\scaledbullet}      % First-level bullets: scaled filled-in
\setlist[itemize,2]{label=\scaledopenbullet} % Second-level bullets: scaled hollow circles

% Boxed section headers with rectangular corners
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable}

\newtcolorbox{mysectionbox}{
  colback=white, colframe=black, boxrule=0.5pt,
  left=4pt, right=4pt, top=2pt, bottom=2pt,
  fontupper=\bfseries, sharp corners
}

% Custom commands for boxed section headers
\newcommand{\sectionbox}[1]{\begin{mysectionbox}#1\end{mysectionbox}}
\newcommand{\subsectionbox}[1]{\vspace{0.5em}\begin{mysectionbox}#1\end{mysectionbox}\vspace{0.2em}}

% Header and footer settings
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} % Clear default headers and footers
\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage} % Place page number at the bottom right corner
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % Remove header line
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt} % Remove footer line

% Custom title format aligned to the left with reduced whitespace
\newcommand{\customtitle}[2]{
  {\Large\textbf{#1}} \\
  {\textit{#2}} \\
  \vspace{0.5em}
}

% Define a custom blockquote environment with a thin vertical bar
\newtcolorbox{myquote}{
  breakable,                    % Allows the box to break across pages
  enhanced,                     % Enables advanced features
  colback=white,                % Background color
  colframe=white,               % Frame color (set to white to hide)
  frame hidden,                 % Hide the frame
  borderline west={0.3pt}{0pt}{black}, % Thin vertical bar on the left
  left=6pt,                     % Left padding
  right=4pt,                    % Right padding
  top=2pt,                      % Top padding
  bottom=2pt,                   % Bottom padding
  sharp corners,                % No rounded corners
  boxrule=0pt,                  % No additional box border
  before skip=6pt,              % Space before the blockquote
  after skip=6pt,               % Space after the blockquote
  parbox=false,                % Adjust to current line width
}

% Redefine the quote environment to use the custom blockquote
\renewenvironment{quote}{\begin{myquote}}{\end{myquote}}

% Begin document
\begin{document}

$if(title)$
\noindent\customtitle{$title$}{$date$} % Left-align title and date
$endif$

% Using the custom section and subsection boxes
\renewcommand{\section}[1]{\sectionbox{#1}}
\renewcommand{\subsection}[1]{\subsectionbox{#1}}

$body$

\end{document}



With the default template:


---
format: pdf
include-in-header: 
  - text: \usepackage{lipsum}
---

#### Normal quote

\lipsum[1][1]

> *"I want block quotes to appear like this"*

\lipsum[2][1]

#### Nested quotes

1.  **Test heading**

    <div>

    > *"A great quote by Person 1"*

    </div>

    The quote above is a great quote.\

    </div>

2.  **Heading 2**

    -   **Person 2**: What he says ....

        <div>

        > *"A great quote by Person 2"*

        </div>

        Here, you can see the great quote from Person 2

        -   What he really think: \lipsum[3][1-3]

            <div>

            > *"What a silly thing I said"*

            </div>

            And that is all. \lipsum[4][1-3]

\lipsum[5][1-3]


With your template but without the Cambria font (sorry, I don't have it) and adding the lipsum package to the template::

To take the template the header must be:
---
format: pdf
template: test_emplate.tex
---


Could you expand on what you mean? When I run the default on the example markdown I provided in the question it does not work.

Of course not if you do not add also the <div><div/> tags as in my example. My example also works with your template,  if (1) you add to the template the lipsum package for the dummy text,  and (2) add template: yourtemplate.tex in the YALM header. In this case the quotes are showed with the vertical gray lines of your example.

I should add that the example is to render directly with quarto. Exported with pandoc "as is" will produce the correct document body, but not the preamble as the YAML options are ignored.
